# How to achieve Synchronous process in Lightning web component

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components

How to Process results from two different @wire methods after the @wires are finished in Lightning web component.

I need to process something in the end based on the results obtained from the above 2 wire results. How to achieve this synchronous process in Lightning web component?

How can I process 2nd @wire method based only after the 1st @wire has processed and got the result from it. How can I make it a synchronous process that it runs one after the another rather than running it as asynchronous process.

Answer (score 4):

Well, you can't control how and when it will execute, because its asynchronous. But here is what you can do.

Let's say you have two wired methods, `wireFunctionA`, `wireFunctionB`. Now, you want to process something only when both of the wired methods executed. So put that code into another function let's say `processSomething`.

```
@wire(wireFunctionA)
wiredA({ error, data }) {
    if (data) {
        this.dataFromA = data;
        this.processSomething();
        this.error = undefined;
    } else if (error) {
        this.error = error;
        this.contacts = undefined;
    }
}


@wire(wireFunctionB)
wiredB({ error, data }) {
    if (data) {
        this.dataFromB = data;
        this.processSomething();
        this.error = undefined;
    } else if (error) {
        this.error = error;
        this.contacts = undefined;
    }
}


processSomething(){
    if(this.dataFromA && this.dataFromB){
        // do your process here.
    }
}
```

In the above code, no matter what is the order of execution `processSomething` will get called only when you have got the results from both of the wired methods. The above code will work in both cases if you are using the **apex** or **uiRecordApi**.

### Additional Tip

Also, there can be a scenario where you are using two apex methods to get data, if possible you can combine those two methods into one, so you will have only one wired apex method.

Comment: To add to this; if (as the question can be read) the second wire, let's call it B, should only be run after the first, let's call it A, has returned results, this implies that B must rely on some detail obtained from A. In this case, ensure that this detail is stored in a tracked property on the component, let's call it valueFromA (initialized to undefined), and leverage it as a parameter to B like ```{ paramX: "$valueFromA"}```. In this case you know that B is called after A since B will only be called once valueFromA has a non-undefined value.

Comment: @Phil W thanks for pointing that out, great idea!

Answer (score 2):

You can use a getter to derive the calculations when you're done. That would look like this:

```
@wire(method1, {params1}) wire1result;
@wire(method2, {params2}) wire2result;
get someProp() {
  if(this.wire1result && this.wire2result) {
    return ...;
  }
  return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question could be understood in two ways:

1. process something only after 2 wire methods been finished
2. run method2 only after method1.

In case it's the first one, the below answers should cover you up.

In case it's the second one, I will go for an imperative apex method instead of a wire, which basically will give you the option to work with Promises and be able to control your flow better and smoothly with `then()`.